# How to retrieve name of Python module calling a function in written in C?

Tags: python, c

I use tutorial from python.org 
"Embedding Python in Another Application"

How to retrieve name of Python module calling a function in written in C:

```
static int numargs=0;

/* Return the number of arguments of the application command line */
static PyObject*
emb_numargs(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, ":numargs"))
        return NULL;
    return Py_BuildValue("i", numargs);
}

static PyMethodDef EmbMethods[] = {
    {"numargs", emb_numargs, METH_VARARGS,
     "Return the number of arguments received by the process."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};
```

Comment: I don't understand what "Can I have module name within this function?" means. Can you explain?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by module name. Usually modules in C are files, and you would be referring to a file name. This however is not possible as your function is static, and cannot be referred to outside it's file.

Answer (score 0):

I have embeddded python to my C++ app. But need to dynamicaly add module.
with

```
Py_InitModule("module1", EmbMethods);
Py_InitModule("module2", EmbMethods);
```

same callback

```
static PyMethodDef EmbMethods[] = {
    {"some_func", some_func, METH_VARARGS,""},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};
```

need something like this

```
static PyObject* some_func(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
     char *p;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s",&p))
        return NULL;

    std::cout<<self->module_name //<<<<<<<< self always == NULL , why?

    return Py_BuildValue("i", numargs);
}
```

python script

```
import module1
print module1.some_func()
print module2.some_func()
```

Output expected:
" module1"
" module2"

Comment: Suggest other solution if you have one